# Why is one variable greater than the other in this code?

Tags: javascript, comparison, numeric

Why is `rfd_total > max_rfd` true?  I don't understand how `rfd_total` can be greater than `max_rfd` in the following code:

```
max_rfd = parseFloat(jQuery('#mx-rfd_'+order_id).val()).toFixed(2);

rfd_total = parseFloat(items_total+tax_total+shipping+allowances*1).toFixed(2);


if( rfd_total > max_rfd)
{   if(isNaN(rfd_total)) alert('rfd_total isNaN'); // not triggered
    if(isNaN(max_rfd)) alert('max_rfd isNaN'); // not triggered
    alert(rfd_total); // alerts 51.16
    alert(max_rfd); // alerts 102.32
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Get a console.log(max_rfd, rdf_total) in there. Get Chrome dev-tools or Firebug out and look at the output. You will be able to see their values and whether they are strings or numbers ;)

Comment: for a quick test in the if statement do if( (rfd_total *1) > (max_rfd * 1)) then it should convert to a number. That should yield the results you want. If it does then apply it the initial variables in replacement of parseFloat.  EDIT: Griffin pointed out that toFixed() returns a string. So multiply by 1 after toFixed() if you wish to use that method.

Comment: @MikeDepies
as you can see I had resorted to the *1 approach in setting rfd_total, but again, what I don't get is why neither isNaN(rfd_total) NOR isNaN(max_rfd) return true?

Comment: @WallabyKid I explained in the comments of my answer :)

Comment: Look at Griffins answer as he mentions the toFixed issue. That is where your issue lies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `rfd_total` an `max_rfd` are Strings.

You will notice that `"51.16" > "102.32"` returns true.

`toFixed()` returns a string.

You will need to coerce your variables to numbers, which you can find out how to do with a quick search.

Or you can keep your code clean and do it properly using a function such as this one

```
function decimalRoundTo(n, decimalPlaces) {
    var d = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    return Math.round(n*d)/d;
}
```

Comment: Well there you go! News to me. That explains soooo much.
I never knew toFixed() retunred a string!
... but then, wouldn't isNaN() return false?

Comment: @WallabyKid, you're right, `isNaN` returns `false`. That is why your alerts aren't triggered. I've added a bit more to my answer btw.

Comment: by return false I meant return true! e.g rfd_total isNaN because it is a string. Right?

Comment: @WallabyKid, `isNaN` attempts to coerce the input parameter to a number. `isNaN("12.13")` returns `false`, but `isNaN("hello")` returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks! I like the function approach cuz I'm so tired of fighting for it.  I'm used to PHP which is much more intuitive regarding strings and numbers

Comment: JavaScript's weak typing can be very handy at times. But in examples like this you really don't want to be seeing `string * number` in your code. Glad I could help.

Comment: A special function is not required. The string returned by *toFixed* can be converted to a number using unary "+", so `+rfd_total > +max_rfd` is sufficient, or if a more explicit converion is required, then something like: `Number(rfd_total) > Number(max_rfd)` will do.

Comment: @RobG did you not read the rest of my answer or the comments here? Also WallabyKid, if this solves your problem please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: @Griffin—yes, I did. My comment is in regard to your statement "Or you can keep your code clean and do it properly using a function", which is made without any justification or explanation of why it might be "proper". If such a function was needed, it would be far simpler as: `function decimalRoundTo(n, places) {return Number(n.toFixed(places));}`. But I don't think that's required since the code itself is no longer than the call and for accuracy's sake, numbers should only be rounded for presentation. So what's the point?